# Convert onEdit function to normal function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have this code for my invoice that send quantity value to stock list in sheet2 but this is an `onEdit` function. I want this function to run by a button at the end of my invoice.

I have tried respond this to a menu button after changing its name from onEdit to (calculation) but working with on menu.
Can anyone tell me how to change it by another way to a normal function.

The code is

```
 //this function is to put quantity to a matching items and once run     then      it   is set off
function onEdit(evt) {
try {
if ( evt.range.getSheet().getName() === "Sheet1" ) {
  // Qty is in column F
  if ( ( evt.range.getRow() > 7 ) && ( evt.range.getRow() < 29 ) && ( evt.range.getColumn() === 6 ) ) {
    var sheet = evt.source.getSheetByName("stock");
    var range = sheet.getDataRange();
    var stock = range.getValues();
    for ( var i = 0; i < stock.length; i++ ) {
      // Compare to column B
      if ( stock[i][0] === evt.range.offset(0, -4, 1, 1).getValue() ) {
        range.offset(i, 2, 1, 1).setValue(evt.value);
        return
      }
    }
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Item <" + evt.range.offset(0, -4, 1, 1).getValue() + "> not found!");
  }
}
} catch(err) {
  Logger.log(err);
}
}
```

Comment: The simplest way will be to create a function that constructs `evt` appropriately, and then calls your function here. Your button would execute the other function. Alternately, rewrite your function here to not need the event object. You can determine what properties are needed by reviewing trigger event object documentation, or by analysing how your code uses the object.

Comment: Do you want it to run with the active range or do you want to manually enter the range's size?

Comment: this is the link where I make invoices for my clients I write it manually.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1O-yrEg-lv_8lgDHrsTDRza1fdYJ-jnBfqMe1Z5U0NOA/edit?usp=sharing